# Meromorphic function $f$ having exactly two zeros $z_1, z_2$ such that both $f'(z_1)$ and $f'(z_2)$ have real part $>0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Do there exist functions like that (defined for all complex numbers except for possible poles)? The function $z \mapsto (z-z_1)(z-z_2)$ does not have this property as an example.

P.S. My mathematical education (PhD) dates back about 30 years but I am still interested very much in Mathematics as a hobby.

Comment: Sorry - In my question I wrote "to zeros". What I meant was "two zeros". I corrected that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g$ be any entire function such that $g(1)=1$ and $g(2)=i$. Let $f(z)=(z-1)(z-2)e^{i\pi g(z)}$. Then the only zeros of $f$ are at $1$ and $2$ and $f'(1)= (1-2)e^{i\pi}=1$, $f'(2)=(2-1) e^{ i\pi g(2)}=e^{-\pi} >0$

Comment: I am looking for functions that have exctly two zeros.

Comment: @Thomas_N I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you! That's a very simple trick. But wouldn't simply taking $g(z)=z$ do the trick too since $exp(i \pi z) = 1$ at $z=2$ ?

Comment: @Thomas_N You are right. I missed that simple point.